# Retrieving certain content from a text file in c#

Tags: c#

I currently have a text file which needs to be clean up and formatted properly. I am using c# read into the text file which currently reads all the contents from the file. However I only want to read certain content from that file.

for example file will contain a list of values shown below.

john,123,abc,ddd,eee,london
11,22,333,444,55,ss,dd,rr,
qw,er,12.

I would like to only read values between **abc** and **444**, the rest i do not want the program to read.

My programme so far

```
    var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Folder\filename.txt");
    Console.WriteLine("file contents = {0}", text);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Would i need to loop through the entire file and display the values i want and is there a simple example

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're working with *CSV* file. In case of *simple* CSV (it doesn't have commas and quotations in values) you can use *Linq*:

```
  var cleared = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\Folder\filename.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(items => items.Skip(2).Take(8))
    .Select(items => items.Join(","));

  File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyData.csv", cleared); 

  // If you want to print out values to console instead of saving them to file: 
  // foreach(var line in cleared) 
  //   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: im working with a txt file. would it will still apply ?

Comment: @r1993: Yes, CSV (Comma Separated Values) is a text format.